# SSH with X11 forwarding in Perl

Tags: perl, ssh, ipc, pipe, x11

I have tried the perl modules Net::SSH:Perl and Net::OpenSSH to no avail.  X11 forwarding does work because if I do a "ssh root@host" and execute an X application such as "xterm" I get a window back.

Here are some things I've tried:

```
    $self->{'ssh'} = Net::OpenSSH->new("root:PW@".$hostname);
    print $self->{'ssh'}->capture("env"); #The display variable is not set so it won't work
    print $self->{'ssh'}->capture("xterm");
```

Nope

```
    $self->{'ssh'} = Net::OpenSSH->new("root:PW@".$hostname, master_opts => ['-X' => '']);
    print $self->{'ssh'}->capture("env"); #The display variable is not set so it won't work
    print $self->{'ssh'}->capture("xterm"); #Nope
    print $self->{'ssh'}->capture({master_opts => ['-X']}, "xterm"); #Nope
```

Nope, now for Net::SSH::Perl

```
    $self->{'ssh'} = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", debug=>0);
    $self->{'ssh'}->login("root","pass");
    my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $self->{'ssh'}->cmd("xterm"); #Nope
```

Nope

```
    $self->{'ssh'} = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", debug=>0, options=>["ForwardX11 yes"]);
    $self->{'ssh'}->login("root","pass");
    my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $self->{'ssh'}->cmd("xterm"); #Nope
```

The only thing that actually works is if I do the following, so I know X11 forwarding is working in Perl.

```
    `ssh root@host xterm`
```

I would rather get the modules working if possible but if I can somehow open up a bidirectional pipe, communicate with SSH and receive data WHEN I WANT TO (similar to how I can $self->{'ssh'}->cmd() and receive the output at any time in my script), I will do that.  I just don't know where to start.  Anyone else did this before?

Comment: "Nope" means, no new window is opening, but you don't get an error message?

Comment: No window opening.  The error is always regarding the DISPLAY variable.  When X11 forwarding is working a SSH creates a pseudo display such as localhost:400 which is an SSH tunnel and sets the DISPLAY variable appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The development version of `Net::OpenSSH` has a new option `forward_X11`. This seems to work:

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("localhost", forward_X11 => 1);
print $ssh->capture({forward_X11 => 1}, "env"); # includes DISPLAY=localhost...
print $ssh->capture({forward_X11 => 1}, "xclock"); # starts the xclock program
```

Note that you have to specify the new option on both the constructor and the actual command.

See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1028837

Comment: Ya I seen that but I was wary on installing a dev module.

Comment: Ahh screw it ill use the dev version.  It's so easy and it works.  Is it possible to install multiple versions of the module.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: There can only be one installed version. But you can use the following trick: build the module with `perl Makefile.PL && make`, but don't run the installation phase. Instead in your programm write `use blib "/path/to/uninstalled/Net-OpenSSH";` on top.